# Retrieve cached transformed AAR dependency classes.jar

Tags: android, gradle, aar

## Context

I'm trying to implement [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka) in a project using the it's fat-jar. To be able to generate documentation. I need the classpath of the dependencies that the project uses. Dokka accepts jars as classpath to be able to generate documentation. I using Groovy to generate a Gradle task to be able to extract the dependencies for each subproject

## Problem

Since the project uses AAR dependencies, I need the classes.jar of those files.

## What I came up so far

I'm able to retrieve the AAR directory in the .gradle cache directory, however that points to, as I said, the AAR. I don't want to unzip the file to be able to extract the classes.jar in it, since that will be very performance-heavy.

```
def classpaths = []
subprojects.each { project ->
    classpaths.addAll(project.android.getBootClasspath().collect { it.path })

    project.configurations.each { configuration ->
        try {
            classpaths.addAll(configuration.files.collect { it.path })
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

This code will retrieve most of the AARs. But it doesn't seem to be printing the dependencies (e.g. Glide)

## Question

How do I get the transformed directory of the dependencies or their classes.jar path for all the dependencies the project uses? I need to be able to get the path dynamically.

**Example of the directory I need:** /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/glide-4.8.0.aar/efaa2fb5a51ab0ecf0ac00dd6a8d019b/jars/classes.jar

Comment: Did you find solution?